# Остановка/Запуск цикла

Tags: javascript, jquery

В поле ввода человек вводит слова, по событию `keyup` запускается функиця поиска в которой циклом ищется совпадения ввода и слова в массиве

```
for (key in data){
  if (data[key].answer.indexOf(inputVal) != -1){
  // Вывожу сообщение из data пользователю
}
```

Нужно сделать, что-бы если при наборе первых символов нет совпадений - то цикл переставал работать (т.к. смысла в этом нет). Но например если из поля ввода стёрли данные и начинают ввода заново, нужно чтобы цикл опять запустился, сделал проверку, Есть совпадения - выводим. Нет совпадений - остановили поиск. Как это можно сделать, второй день голову ломаю. Заранее спасибо

Comment: `break`?.......

Comment: Врядли...например я вышел из цикла через `break`, но при след. `keyup` я опять войду в цикл...

Comment: Разве не в этом смысл поиска? При новом вводе искать заново.

Comment: Хотя, да, с break, вы правы, спасибо)

Comment: Вам придется сделать флаг, который будет сигнализировать о том, запускать цикл или нет. Если результата нет, то устанавливаем его в false и запоминаем последнюю комбинацию. При следующем вводе сравниваем, если совпадают первые символы с комбинацией, то не ищем. Если не совпадают, то сбрасываем в true и обнуляем комбинацию, что бы поиск продолжал работать.

Comment: @Alex Krass  ага..спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать, а то с `break;` чуток не то..)

Comment: @AlexKrass Знаете, ваш вариант решения не очень устойчив к тому, что пользователь может нажать кнопку backspace (удалить предыдущий символ)... и это ещё ладно: можно ведь n раз нажать кнопку left и потом нажать backspace. Могу предложить более интересный концепт расчёта флага, раз уж автору нужно. Нужно запоминать результат каждого запроса в массив сделанных запросов. И перед тем как лезть за очередным запросом в базу для asdf проверять наличие уже сделанного запроса для asd (без последнего символа). Если для asd ничего не найдено -- нет смысла лезить и за asd*, логично?

Comment: @AK событие onkeyup хорошо реагирует на нажатие клавиши backspace и клавиш перехода по тексту, поэтому в данном случае ничего плохого не произойдет. Скрипт подхватит изменения в момент нажатия и сравнение будет оставаться верным.

Comment: @AlexKrass Да? Не знал. А можно подробнее для несведующих пояснить? Допустим, вариант "нажата стрелка влево, а потом backspace". Или ссылку дать.

Comment: @AK вот тут на коленке набросал пример, что бы поиграться: https://jsfiddle.net/L3e2277o/1/ Ну а в качестве документации конечно [сайт mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup), но я опытным путем проверял.